# Tidy way of passing ADO.net SqlParameters to a method as an optional list/array/other

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net, overriding

I have a very simple ADO.net helper class ([copy here](http://www.heavencore.co.uk/forum/viewthread.php?thread_id=185&pid=423#post_423)) that helped us move from working with classic adodb to ado.net, i.e. usage is *very* simple:

```
Public db As New SimpleDataAccess
Public RS As New DataTable

db.ConnectionStringName = "DEV"
db.ConnectDatabase()
db.Execute_Query(RS, "SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE IntColumn = " & tools.parseint(EmployeeID, 0) & " or TextColumn = '" & db.Escape("bla'blabla") & "'")
For Each DB_Row As DataRow In RS.Rows
   response.write(DB_Row("IntColumn"))
Next
db.CloseDatabase()
```

Now whilst this works great it relies on the user to use a `parseint()` and `Escape()` function to prevent sql injection etc (and even then in a crude way) - what i would like to do is develop an 2nd version of the `Execute_NonQuery()` & `Execute_Query()` functions that accepts `SqlParameter()'s`
 in some way.

What would be the tidiest way to pass mutliple `SqlParameter()'s` optionally to the `Execute_NonQuery()` & `Execute_Query()`  methods?

PS: This is used in .net 2.0 & .net 3.5 frameworks only

**Edit 1 - My first attempt**

In my first attempt ive just given the method a new name (V2), You'll also note that ive added an optional parameter called `ParamList` which is a `List(Of SqlParameter)`:

```
Public Function Execute_QueryV2(ByRef TargetDataTable As DataTable, ByVal CommandText As String, Optional ByVal ParamList As List(Of SqlParameter) = Nothing, Optional ByVal CommandType As CommandType = CommandType.Text) As Boolean
    If CommandText = "" Then
        m_ErrorDesc = "Error running query: Query text was blank"
        EmailError(m_ErrorDesc)
        Return False
    Else
        Try
            NukeDataTable(TargetDataTable)
            m_db_Command = New SqlCommand(CommandText, m_db)
            m_db_Command.CommandType = CommandType
            If IsNothing(ParamList) = False Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To ParamList.Count - 1
                    m_db_Command.Parameters.Add(ParamList(i))
                Next
            End If
            m_db_DataAdapter.SelectCommand = m_db_Command
            m_db_DataAdapter.Fill(TargetDataTable)
            m_db_DataAdapter.Dispose()
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            m_ErrorDesc = "Error running query: " & ex.Message & "<br /><br />Query:<hr />" & CommandText
            EmailError(m_ErrorDesc)
            Return False
        End Try
    End If
End Function
```

This means that my usage can be done as follows:

```
Dim QueryParameters As New List(Of SqlParameter)
QueryParameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@value", Trim(Request.QueryString("value"))))
db.Execute_QueryV2(rs, "SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE value = @value", QueryParameters)
```

My only problem with this is that any page using my db class will need to include `System.Collections.Generic` - is there a tider way of doing this that wouldnt require the extra include in all calling pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override a non virtual method.  However, you can create a new class derived from SimpleDataAccess class and mark a new method as Shadows.  Also, to hide it from the users of your class, mark it with the [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx) attribute.  Now, the VS intellisence will not display it and you can create new public methods with the required signature.

**Update**
I would pass the command object itself.  It contains the list of parameters and all required infrastructure.  If it is impossible, I would either create a Dictionary which is a dictionary containing pairs parameterName and its value, or a List object containing the list of required parameters with values set.

Comment: Interesting, however the main part of my question really is how best to accept parameters as a method parameter and use these within the method via a sql command - i.e. I’ve seen some examples that pass parameters in via arrays etc but these look complicating - how would you approach that segment of my question?

Comment: Cheers, I’ve edited my question with my first attempt using a `List()` - the whole point of this class was to avoid having to deal with the command object at page level - this is what I’ve attempted to do in my first edit - however you'll note that i now have a new problem regarding `System.Collections.Generic` - any ideas?

Comment: @HeavenCore, your problem with including the System.Collections.Generic namespace to the page is unclear to me.  Anyway, if you do not like to add this namespace, you can create a new class which will hold the List of SQLParameters inside.  Thus, you will still have type safety and hide the System.Collections.Generic namespace from all your pages page.  Meantime, your method should now accept your own class instance which holds the list of SQLParameters and work with it.